# How to include more than one build in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, cs50

I created a makefile to compile hello.c and it looks like this:

```
    1 #the compiler to use
    2 CC = clang
    3
    4 #compiler flags:
    5 # -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
    6 # -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
    7 CFLAGS = -g -Wall
    8
    9 #files to link:
   10 LFLAGS = -lcs50
   11
   12 #the name to use for both the target source file and the output file:
   13 TARGET = hello
   14
   15 all: $(TARGET)
   16 $(TARGET): $(TARGET).c
   17     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c $(LFLAGS)
```

I also have 2 other programs named: int.c and float.c that I would like to include in TARGET but I get this result:

```
  make: Circular hello <- hello dependency dropped.
  make: Circular int <- hello dependency dropped.
  make: Circular int <- int dependency dropped.
  clang -g -Wall -o hello int float hello int float.c -lcs50
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'int'
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'float'
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'hello'
  clang: error: no such file or directory: 'int'
  make: *** [int] Error 1
```

Comment: What exactly does the failing `Makefile` look like?

Answer (score 0):

So you have roughly the right idea, but the execution isn't quite perfect!  The biggest clue as to what might be going wrong is the following line in your output:

```
clang -g -Wall -o hello int float hello int float.c -lcs50
```

As you can see it's simply substituted in "hello int float" twice, once with a ".c" added to the end. So what can we do about it?

---

Although less common, using a list of variables separated by spaces (i.e. `TARGET = hello int float`) is valid, and your rule (`${TARGET}: ...`) will indeed evaluate once for each item in the list.  There are ways to add the `.c` suffix to every item in your list (the [`addsuffix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) function), however we can do this in a more "Make-y" way.

#### Pattern Rules & Automatic Variables

In order to fix how we reference things from our target definition, what you are looking for are [Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) and [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).  Pattern rules let us make rules which are very genral and follow a certain pattern, and the automatic variables let us reference parts of our rule definition in the commands run.

```
...
all: ${TARGETS}
%: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
```

We did two things here, first we replaced the rule with `%: %.c`.  This says, there is a target with some name, and it depends on some file which is the same as that with a `.c` at the end.

Secondly, we replaced the references to `${TARGET}` in our make command with the automatic variables. `$@` refers to the target name, and `$^` to the list of dependencies (in this case, only one).

---

#### Some further improvements

A slightly more conventional way to use pattern rules is to have a suffix on the output as well:

```
TARGETS = hello.o int.o float.o
all: ${TARGETS}
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
```

However, we like to be lazy so we can automate this further with a few more tricks which I have commented, giving a makefile something like this:

```
# The compiler to use
CC = clang

# Compiler flags:
# -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
# -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

# Files to link:
LFLAGS = -lcs50

# Find all the files ending with .c using the shell command
SOURCEFILES = $(shell find . -type f -name "*.c")

# Convert all of these files to have .o as their suffix with a substitution
OUTPUTFILES = ${SOURCEFILES:.c=.o}

# Our "PHONY" rules; all make targets correspond with a produced file 
# (This is how it can be clever about knowing when it can skip rules
# if no files have changed.  We never make a file called "all" or "clean"
# as these are rules for our convenience - aka PHONY rules.)
.PHONY: all clean

# Build all our output files (.o files)
all: ${OUTPUTFILES}

# Remove all our output files
clean:
        rm -v ${OUTPUTFILES}

# The rule that tells us how to make a .o file from a .c file.
$.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)
```

Now we can add any .c file, and it will be compiled with the options you set! Changing `TARGET` variables is now a thing of the past!